# Short-Circuiting Interaction with Ternary Operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, boolean, conditional-operator, short-circuiting

I'm currently learning JavaScript and I encountered this problem:

```js
const numArray = [1, 6, 9, 4, 21, 8, 15];

const sumEvenOdd = numArray.reduce((acc, current) => 
   console.log(acc) && current % 2 === 0 
      ? acc.map(i => i.hasOwnProperty('even') ? {...i, even: i.even + current} : i)
      : acc.map(i => i.hasOwnProperty('odd') ? {...i, odd: i.odd + current} : i), 
      [{"even": 0, color: 'red'}, {"odd": 0, color: 'green'}]
);
```

```js
const numArray = [1, 6, 9, 4, 21, 8, 15];

const sumEvenOdd = numArray.reduce((acc, current) => 
   console.log(acc) || current % 2 === 0 
      ? acc.map(i => i.hasOwnProperty('even') ? {...i, even: i.even + current} : i)
      : acc.map(i => i.hasOwnProperty('odd') ? {...i, odd: i.odd + current} : i), 
      [{"even": 0, color: 'red'}, {"odd": 0, color: 'green'}]
);
```

When you run each of the above code, you'll notice that the first one only modifies the **"odd"** property which is not what I'm expecting when I used the **&&** operator but when I changed it to the **||** operator I got the code that I was expecting originally. Can someone explain to me how I got those 2 outputs?

Comment: why are you using `&&` or `||` in the reduce function? `console.log` always returns undefined which is false. Why include it in a boolean operation?

Comment: I'd highly recommend using block (`{ ... }`) in your arrow function. That way you can have multiple statements and use a simple if-else construction. It will greatly improve readability and lowers the chances of errors like the one you are experiencing now.

Comment: console.log does not return anything...... So it is never going to be truthy. So `&&` fails.

Comment: `console.log()` returns `undefined`, so essentially you're ending up with: `(false && <true/false>) ? <map even numbers> : <map odd numbers>`

Comment: @Ivar I tried what you recommended but I got an error: https://imgur.com/a/kKhZAHG

Comment: @ColstonBod-oy Use something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/g7hznb9w/2/).

Comment: @Ivar Why can't I use ternary?

Comment: @ColstonBod-oy You _can_, and if you use it properly it will most likely work. But an important aspect of software engineering is the readability of your code. While programming you generally spend way more time reading code than you spend writing it, so you should make your code as easy to understand as possible. Nesting everything together in line, using multiple different operators requires quite a bit of mental effort to understand what that code is doing.